# How to scrape over a loop from a database?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from a database that doesn't allow downloading directly. I have been able to scrape data from a single species but I am trying to do it for 159 species. This is why I wanted to create a loop that could be helpful

```
test <- data.frame(site = c("url=1",
                            "url=2"),
                   html.node = "td.DataText", stringsAsFactors = F)
library(rvest)
# an empty list, to fill with the scraped data
empty_list <- list()

for (i in 1:nrow(test)){
  datatext <- pubs[i, 1]   
  datatext2 <- pubs[i, 2]       
  # scrape it!    
  empty_list[[i]] <- read_html(datatext)  %>% html_nodes(datatext2) %>% html_text()

}
names(empty_list) <- test$site

empty <- as.data.frame(empty_list)
```

This is what I've tried so far. This is only for 2 species as indicated by FID=1 and FID=2 in the URL. There are 159 species. This is why I wanted  a for loop that goes from 1:159 and populates the dataframe as it does with this current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out!

```
url="url=1"
webpage <- read_html(url)

Data.Label <- webpage %>%
  html_nodes("td.DataLabel") %>%
  html_text()

Label <- as.data.frame(t(Data.Label))
#Obtains the data labels in a dataframe that is tranposed.

Data.Text <- lapply(paste0('url=', 1:159),
                function(url){
                  url %>% read_html() %>% 
                    html_nodes("td.DataText") %>% 
                    html_text()
                })
#Creates a list of all the data text needed to populate the table

Eco.Table <- as.data.frame(Data.Text)
#Convert list into dataframe.

Eco.Table <- Eco.Table[-c(39:42), ]
#Remove irrelevant rows 

Eco.Table <- as.data.frame(t(Eco.Table))
#Transpose the dataframe into rows

rownames(Eco.Table) <- NULL
colnames(Eco.Table) <- as.character(unlist(Label))
#Reset row names and add column labels
```